# Filtered or non-filtered soymilk maker?

Tags: vegan, tofu, soymilk

In the process of making soymilk for **drinking** it, using it as diary replacement in **vegan cooking** or preparing **tofu**, one have to strain the mixture to remove the okara. There are lot of soymilk makers available. Some (like the *Soyabella*) **include a filter** so that every steps of the process are automatized. Yet, the most recent makers like the *Soyapower PLUS* are **filter-less**, which means one have to filter the milk at hand with a strainer.

Why do they removed the filter in the recent soymakers ? Is it to make the cleaning easier, or does it improve the quality to boil the milk together with the okara ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an old SoyaQuick (mine has a filter, newer models don't), and I think it was largely a cleaning concern. The tiny perforations in the filter clogged very easily, and the instruction manual had a whole section of bizarre tips for cleaning it (soak it in bleach! squeeze a soapy sponge to one side to force the suds through!)

There's also some marketing speak about "leaving in the perfect amount of pulp for your taste!" but that sounds like bull to me.